# How to create a folder via mkdir from a file path?

Tags: makefile, directory, mkdir

I have a relative path, let's say

```
a/b/c/d.txt
```

and none of those folder exists, so for that file to be created I need all of the folders to be created, which is possible via `mkdir -p`, but how do I strip the file name to get only

```
a/b/c
```

in a Makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GNU Make, use its [`dir`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) function, e.g.

**Makefile**

```
.PHONY: all

all:
    echo $(dir a/b/c/d.txt)
```

which runs like:

```
$ make
echo a/b/c/
a/b/c/
```

Comment: Wow, why couldn't I find that before? Thanks anyways!

Comment: I got to `$(subst $(lastword $(subst /, ,a/b/c/d.txt)),,a/b/c/d.txt)` after playing around a bit, but that is obviously inferior